# How can I restore previous activity after receiving call?

Tags: android, call

My app has on main activity and it displays only one another activity as singleton. So my app has one main activity and another activity running on the main activity. 
When I get an call, the activated screen changes to call screen of Android. But when I return to my app, I can see only main activity. The activated activity does not come back.
In this case, do I have to save the activated activity in my app and start it again after receiving call? If then, please let me know what the good way to solve this is.

Comment: My case was not normal stuff. I investigate my menifest.xml again and found that a option for starting activities was wierd. android:nohistory = "true", so I got rid of it. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: In order to show appreciation to the community that has been answering your questions, please go to your previous questions and, if sufficiently answered, mark as answered and/or upvote answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Simply override `onSaveInstanceState` to save the state and `onRestoreInstanceState` to restore to the saved state.